# Correctness - Nullcheck of value previously dereferenced, FOD issue in try with resource

Tags: java, fortify

In my code I am getting "Correctness - Nullcheck of value previously dereferenced" Fortify issue on an Input Stream in try with Resource.

```
@Bean
public String publicKey() throws IOException {
    URL resourceUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("something.txt");
    try (InputStream inputStream = resourceUrl.openStream()) {
        **BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));**
```

The error is thrown in the Buffered Reader initialization line.

Resource URL is taken from:

```
URL resourceUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("something.txt");
```

How can I address this in try with Resource scenario?

Comment: It's really unclear what line exactly you get an error. I don't see any null checks in the code you post. Do you check `resourceUrl` for at some later point in that method?

Comment: The error is coming in the Buffered Reader init line, code updated.

Comment: What is a "FOD issue"? Never heard.

Comment: FOD is Fortify on Demand, a vulnerability detection tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix (clean SonarQube Report) this issue as follows:

Approach 1: try with resource has a default null check, so to avoid redundant de-referenced null check issue move the statement out of try with resource.

```
URL resourceUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("something");

    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = resourceUrl.openStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        try {
            bufferedReader.lines().forEach(builder::append);
        } finally {
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex){ //rethrow the same and handle in the calling function }
```

Note: This style of nesting try...finally in try...catch is  particularly useful when the finally block throws the same exceptions as the rest of the code (which is common with java.io operations.)

Approach 2: Simply remove the try block and make the function throws IOException and handle directly in the calling function.

Comment: I think the approach 1, you mentioned is apt. This worked for me.